# Macro Runs if loaded as an add-in fails as part of personal workbook

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have a function for Triangular Distribution that runs from an add  in  but gives the #Name error when I try and run it from a module in my Personal Workbook. I changed the names of the macro to make sure that was not an issue. This is the code.

```
Public Function TriangD2(mn As Double, md As Double, mx As Double)

    Application.Volatile
     rr = Rnd()
    Calculate
    ' Triangular
     If rr = ((md - mn) / (mx - mn)) Then
        TriangD = md
        Else
           If rr < ((md - mn) / (mx - mn)) Then
           TriangD = mn + Sqr(rr * (mx - mn) * (md - mn))
           Else
           TriangD = mx - Sqr((1 - rr) * (mx - mn) * (mx - md))
           End If
     End If
End Function
```

I am using Excel 2011 for Mac. The reason I am trying to change from an add in is because with the ad in open if I try and rename a sheet Excel crashes. If I disable the add in it does not.

Comment: Is it in a workbook module that's called `TriangD2`? Also, try adding that to a completely new workbook and see if you get an error then too.  Finally, you never set `TriangD2`, you're just using `TriangD`, so it won't return anything.

Comment: See is adding [Option Explicit](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/3554/always-use-option-explicit#t=20170731165427545335) to the top of the module code sheet gives you additional information.